# Why is Facebook inserting a preload script for my app's css in HTTP when my page's reference is in HTTPS?

Tags: css, facebook, caching, ssl

In our app (https://apps.facebook.com/testedenivel), we explicitly reference the page css in a https link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2asm4nez8zghw.cloudfront.net/content/app-teste-de-nivel.css?v=0.96.02" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

But strangely, Facebook is preloading this this css file as a HTTP link. At some point before, we used this HTTP url but later we changed it to HTTPS, and now it seems that Facebook is using a former, cached version of that url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new Image().src = "http:\/\/www.talkfast.com.br\/content\/app-teste-de-nivel.css";
</script>
```

The problem is that when the user enters our app via secure browsing, the HTTP link preloading is causing the browser to alert our users that some insecure content is about to be loaded. We'd like to know how to tell Facebook to remove this preloading script, or at least to use our current HTTPS url, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new Image().src = "https://d2asm4nez8zghw.cloudfront.net/content/app-teste-de-nivel.css?v=0.96.02";
</script>
```

There seems to be scarcity of reference regarding this issue on the web, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not test this solution in facebook app but on wild web you can use this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

as proof :)
http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

With this all resources loaded with page protocol, so user don't see confirmation about unsecured elements on page.

---

Just create test app with Heroku and my chromium not angry about https resouces inside frame so problems depends on browser.